# Quality check failing in Facebook Native Ads in Android

Tags: android, facebook, ads, native-ads

I am facing Facebook Quality check failing issue. I have status app which is using recycle view and Facebook Native Ads. I am getting alert on Facebook Dashboard:-

[image]

I am using Ads after every 4 status and initializing Ads manager in Adapter like this:-

```java
mNativeAdsManager = new NativeAdsManager(activity.getApplication(), activity.getString(R.string.FACEBOOK_ADS_NATIVE_PLACEMENT_ID), 5);
initNativeAds();
```

Clickable views are only title and call to action button as defined in Facebook Doc.

```java
// Create a list of clickable views
List<View> clickableViews = new ArrayList<>();
clickableViews.add(nativeAdTitle);
clickableViews.add(nativeAdCallToAction);
```

All are good in app but why Quality check is going fail still don't know. Here is Ad image:-

[image]

Here is the app link which is showing ads on every page for example:- [Daily Status](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=coders.hub.daily_status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ad takes too much space than necessary.

In the screenshot you attached above, the ad is taking way too much space, and I can imagine users trying to swipe up, but then accidentally ending up clicking on the area that was mentioned in the email that Facebook sent.

What I'm trying to say is, there is no way for user to swipe up without touching the ad, and then swiping up, which might lead to invalid clicks.

Try reducing the height of your ad, or maybe use Native Banner ads, it should decrease accidental clicks.

Comment: This is Native banner ads and I have set only minimum height 250dp in MediaView(android:minHeight="250dp") rest height is coming from Ads automatically.

Comment: why would you set minHeight though? This ad looks like it's a full native ad and not banner. Try following the guide to implement native banner properly.

Comment: Yes checked right now and got new thing. Thanks a lot and will check again after doing improvement in Facebook dashboard.

Comment: It was about minimum height set to 250dp and some other old code too.

Comment: Well.. when you're trying to implement banner ad, make it look like a banner. lol. Plus your ads title and subtitle are also being clipped even if there is no view there. Look how "Reward your curio.." is being shown, it'll reduce the quality of ad and might reduce the clicks you'd get.